# Rust JSON API Request Formatting

Tags: rust

I am trying to perform a search request given the API structure by:
https://api.wigle.net/swagger#/

Currently, I have attempted to perform a /api/v2/network/search through the given structure by doing this (sorry for the long url!):

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate reqwest;
use reqwest::Error;
use serde_json;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Output {
    trilat: f64,
    trilong: f64,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let request_url = format!("https://api.wigle.net/api/v2/network/search?first=0&latrange1={lat_range_min}&latrange2={lat_range_max}&longrange1={long_range_min}&longrange2={long_range_max}&freenet=false&paynet=false&ssid={ssid}",
                              lat_range_min = "41.159",
                              lat_range_max = "42.889",
                              long_range_min = "-73.5081",
                              long_range_max = "-69.7398",
                              ssid= "XFINITY"
                            );

    let mut response = reqwest::get(&request_url)?;

    println!("{:?}", response);

    //let result: Vec<Output> = response.json()?;
    //println!("{}", result[0].trilat);
    Ok(())
}
```

The output I get is:

```sh
Response { url: "https://api.wigle.net/api/v2/network/search?first=0&latrange1=41.159&latrange2=42.889&longrange1=-73.5081&longrange2=-69.7398&freenet=false&paynet=false&ssid=xfinity", status: 401, headers: 
{"server": "nginx/1.16.1", "date": "Tue, 24 Dec 2019 19:51:14 GMT", "content-type": "application/json", "content-length": "14", "connection": "keep-alive"} }
```

However if you were to do an actual request, you would get detailed api output from WiGLE.

What do I do in order to get the correct output so I can parse it as a json output?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a Rust coder, but aren't you supposed to call something like [`json()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.9.24/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.json) on the response?

Comment: Could you determine the final aim of your programme? So ... You would like to print json or to treat it as a json within other parts of your programme?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, because the response I am getting isn't even the correct response I have not gotten to the parsing part. I wanted to extract the trilat and trilong data out from the API, but the output I get is not the actual data, but the headers.

Comment: Update: I've realized you needed an authorization header for this API in order to work. Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This crate doesn't support such a possibility to transform its type `Response` to the `serde_json::Value` type. But you can implement it by yourself.

You should define your structure and operate on it. For instanse it may be somehow like the following:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use serde_json;
use reqwest;
use reqwest::Error;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Req {
  url: String,
  status: u16,
  headers: HashMap<String, String>,
  body: Option<serde_json::Value>
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let request_url = format!("https://api.wigle.net/api/v2/network/search?first=0&latrange1={lat_range_min}&latrange2={lat_range_max}&longrange1={long_range_min}&longrange2={long_range_max}&freenet=false&paynet=false&ssid={ssid}",
                              lat_range_min = "41.159",
                              lat_range_max = "42.889",
                              long_range_min = "-73.5081",
                              long_range_max = "-69.7398",
                              ssid= "xfinity"
                            );
    let mut response = reqwest::get(&request_url)?;
    let mut hm = HashMap::new();
    for (key, val) in response.headers().into_iter() {
      hm.insert(key.as_str().to_owned(), val.to_str().ok().unwrap_or("").to_owned());
    }

    let req = Req {status: response.status().as_u16(), url: request_url, body: response.json().ok(), headers: hm};

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&req).unwrap_or("".to_owned()));


    Ok(())
}
```

to improve such a solution you can implement the trait `From` not to be so descriptive each time.

Comment: Hello, sorry if I wasn't being clear, but even with your code I get the same output with status code 401 unauthorized. However if I were to visit the fully constructed request in a web browser https://api.wigle.net/api/v2/network/search?first=0&latrange1=41.159&latrange2=42.889&longrange1=-73.5081&longrange2=-69.7398&freenet=false&paynet=false&ssid=xfinity it would give me the intended output